# Solr fullimport or delta import with mysql

Tags: mysql, solr, solr4

Im using solr 4.4 ,my config.xml file is as given below.

First time i do a full import of 40000 rows ,it is indexed.

Now in my application i add one more row the total count comes to 40001,i need

to do the full import or delta import?

I know that the delta import is applied to a row which is indexed ,

What is the approach when a new row is added to mysql ,do we need to use full

import of all 40001 data ?

```
    <dataConfig> 
     <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" user="uname" password="pwd" batchSize="1" />  
     <document name="resource">   
      <entity name="resource" query="SELECT * FROM resource" 
      deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM resource  WHERE ref = '${dataimporter.delta.ref}'"
      deltaQuery="SELECT * FROM resource  WHERE last_modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'" transformer="RegexTransformer">    
        <field column="ref" name="ref"/>    
        <field column="name" name="name"/> 
................
............    
    </entity>   
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article right from the documentation , that talks about a delta import via full import approach with being efficient . Have a look at it here https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerDeltaQueryViaFullImport . Hope this helps :)